# Identify client by unique ID

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

What is the best way to identify a client within PHP?

Obviously an IP-address wouldn't be safe nor would it distinguish multiple clients coming from the same IP-address.

I **don't** want to use sessions.

Comment: you said it - unique id

Comment: I don't think you can make it more unique than IP without sessions / login stuff.

Comment: Why don't you want to use sessions?

Comment: If you don't want to use sessions, then you're limited to telepathic abilities of your server. I just hope you got the latest version.

Comment: @N.B. Can you give me a link to the telepathic ability part of the PHP documentation?

Comment: @Fred Yes, but only during the login till the logout timespan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks God, there is **NO** unique id to track our browsers. So, you have to limit your desire for identification to mere cookies.

Comment: Your answer makes completely sense, I was hoping there was someway to do this though, besides cookies...

Comment: What is the purpose for your tracking? There are methods, unreliable in general but usable in some circumstances

Comment: Identifying user sessions. Cookies are being "deprecated" in my country.

Comment: The internet will always need cookies! -> I think they just want you to warn your visitors.

Comment: You got to live in the future

Comment: 1. There is no country where *direct* cookies are deprecated. There are limitations for 3-d party cookies only 2. **Sessions do use cookies** to identify a client.

Comment: AFAIK, if the user agrees to accepting your cookies in order to be authenticated, there is no legal issue regarding cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Other than cookies / sessions (based on unique id'd cookies) your only choice is called 'fingerprinting'. The idea is to make browser fingerprints out of multiple small details known about the client. A very simple example is:

```
$unique_id = md5( $client_ip . $client_user_agent );
```

This can become more accurate than most would imagine when you combine details such as: java vm version, flash version, installed fonts, ... all available information when you have access to the content page itself. Of course breaking the fingerprint becomes as easy as updating to a new flash player but for short lived cookie-less sessions, fingerprints do the trick.

Comment: My brother also uses Chrome. :( We share the same computer!

Comment: Sharing the computer would defeat EVERY tracking technique of course, even cookie based sessions .. "Your brother logs into facebook, walks away, you post a message to his wall" how on earth is facebook supposed to know you are not your brother...

Comment: My brother must be intelligent enough to LOG OUT. Your method provides no way of logging out and as such can only be used to 'monitor' a certain client, not identify him/her. You did not state that and I wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

I really like **smassey**'s suggestion (above) of FingerPrinting.  Our issue is making it so we lockout people who enter the wrong credentials N times and not lockout anyone else.  We need to know something from the client workstation that we can rely upon that tells us something unique.  IP address works if there is no HTTP proxy. Proxies confuse this. 
We are not looking for a user's real name or anything private but keeping bad guys/gals locked out.
The nice thing is that it does it without sessions, without cookies and works even if they change browsers.
Not sure what parameters we will use but I will be looking in PHP to see what is available.  I wonder if total space on primary local storage is available.  Mac and Linux compatibility is a must nowadays.